# separate columns based on genre

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataset for movies recommendation and want to separate the genre feature into different genre columns . The column has all the genres together and seperates them with '|'.

What is the best way to do it?

```
     movieId      title                                genres
0       1         Toy Story (1995)                     Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy
1       2         Jumanji (1995)                       Adventure|Children|Fantasy
2       3         Grumpier Old Men (1995)              Comedy|Romance
3       4         Waiting to Exhale (1995)             Comedy|Drama|Romance
4       5         Father of the Bride Part II (1995)   Comedy
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df = df['genres'].str.get_dummies('|')
print (df)
   Adventure  Animation  Children  Comedy  Drama  Fantasy  Romance
0          1          1         1       1      0        1        0
1          1          0         1       0      0        1        0
2          0          0         0       1      0        0        1
3          0          0         0       1      1        0        1
4          0          0         0       1      0        0        0
```

and if need add back as new columns add [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df.join(df.pop('genres').str.get_dummies('|'))
print (df)
   movieId                               title   ...     Fantasy  Romance
0        1                    Toy Story (1995)   ...           1        0
1        2                      Jumanji (1995)   ...           1        0
2        3             Grumpier Old Men (1995)   ...           0        1
3        4            Waiting to Exhale (1995)   ...           0        1
4        5  Father of the Bride Part II (1995)   ...           0        0
```